# adding email under author affiliation

Tags: author, email

How can I reformat the following so that it looks like below NAACL:

```
​%\author{Mona Jalal \\
%  Computer Science Department \\ Boston University \\
%  {\tt jalal@bu.edu} \\\And
%  Kate K. Mays, Lei Guo \\
%  Emerging Media Studies \\ Boston University\\
%  {\tt kkmays@bu.edu} \\
%  {\tt guolei@bu.edu} \\\And
%    Margrit Betke \\
%  Computer Science Department \\ Boston University\\
%  {\tt betke@bu.edu} \\}
\author[*]{Mona Jalal}
\author[**]{Kate K. Mays}
\author[**]{Lei Guo}
\author[*]{Margrit Betke}
\affil[*]{Computer Science Department, Boston University}
\affil[**]{Emerging Media Studies, Boston University}
```

Basically, I want to add {jalal, kkmays, guolei, betke}@bu.edu under the affiliation we all have the same domain.
[image]

Ours currently look like:
[image]

```
%
% File naaclhlt2018.tex
%
%% Based on the style files for NAACL-HLT 2018, which were
%% Based on the style files for ACL-2015, with some improvements
%%  taken from the NAACL-2016 style
%% Based on the style files for ACL-2014, which were, in turn,
%% based on ACL-2013, ACL-2012, ACL-2011, ACL-2010, ACL-IJCNLP-2009,
%% EACL-2009, IJCNLP-2008...
%% Based on the style files for EACL 2006 by 
%%e.agirre@ehu.es or Sergi.Balari@uab.es
%% and that of ACL 08 by Joakim Nivre and Noah Smith

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[hyperref]{naaclhlt2018}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{url}

\aclfinalcopy % Uncomment this line for the final submission
%def\aclpaperid{61} %  Enter the acl Paper ID here
%setlength\titlebox{5cm}
% You can expand the titlebox if you need extra space
% to show all the authors. Please do not make the titlebox
% smaller than 5cm (the original size); we will check this
% in the camera-ready version and ask you to change it back.

\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc bib}\TeX}

\title{paper title}

%\author{Mona Jalal \\
%  Computer Science Department \\ Boston University \\
%  {\tt jalal@bu.edu} \\\And
%  Kate K. Mays, Lei Guo \\
%  Emerging Media Studies \\ Boston University\\
%  {\tt kkmays@bu.edu} \\
%  {\tt guolei@bu.edu} \\\And
%    Margrit Betke \\
%  Computer Science Department \\ Boston University\\
%  {\tt betke@bu.edu} \\}
\author[*]{Mona Jalal}
\author[**]{Kate K. Mays}
\author[**]{Lei Guo}
\author[*]{Margrit Betke}
\affil[*]{Computer Science Department, Boston University}
\affil[**]{Emerging Media Studies, Boston University} 


%%\renewcommand\Authands{  }
%%\date{}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE, at least it would be helpful to know what documentclass this uses.

Comment: @MatthiasArras please check above

Comment: With the `stackengine` package, you should be able to do something like `\affil[*]{\stackunder{Computer Science Department, Boston University}{\ttfamily\{jalal, betke\}@bu.edu}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the `\affil` command from the `naaclhlt2018` package that you use to provide an `email` option, i.e. basically removed the counter display. I have not cleaned up the code, whatsoever.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[hyperref]{naaclhlt2018}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{url}

\aclfinalcopy % Uncomment this line for the final submission
%def\aclpaperid{61} %  Enter the acl Paper ID here
%setlength\titlebox{5cm}
% You can expand the titlebox if you need extra space
% to show all the authors. Please do not make the titlebox
% smaller than 5cm (the original size); we will check this
% in the camera-ready version and ask you to change it back.

\newcommand\BibTeX{B{\sc bib}\TeX}

\title{paper title}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\email[2][]%
   {\newaffiltrue\let\AB@blk@and\AB@pand
      \if\relax#1\relax\def\AB@note{\AB@thenote}\else\def\AB@note{\relax}%
        \setcounter{Maxaffil}{0}\fi
      \begingroup
        \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
        \def\thanks{\protect\thanks}\def\footnote{\protect\footnote}%
        \@temptokena=\expandafter{\AB@authors}%
        {\def\\{\protect\\\protect\Affilfont}\xdef\AB@temp{#2}}%
         \xdef\AB@authors{\the\@temptokena\AB@las\AB@au@str
         \protect\\[\affilsep]\protect\Affilfont\AB@temp}%
         \gdef\AB@las{}\gdef\AB@au@str{}%
        {\def\\{, \ignorespaces}\xdef\AB@temp{#2}}%
        \@temptokena=\expandafter{\AB@affillist}%
        \xdef\AB@affillist{\the\@temptokena \AB@affilsep
          \AB@affilnote{}\protect\Affilfont\AB@temp}%
      \endgroup
       \let\AB@affilsep\AB@affilsepx
}
\makeatother

%\author{Mona Jalal \\
%  Computer Science Department \\ Boston University \\
%  {\tt jalal@bu.edu} \\\And
%  Kate K. Mays, Lei Guo \\
%  Emerging Media Studies \\ Boston University\\
%  {\tt kkmays@bu.edu} \\
%  {\tt guolei@bu.edu} \\\And
%    Margrit Betke \\
%  Computer Science Department \\ Boston University\\
%  {\tt betke@bu.edu} \\}
\author[*]{Mona Jalal}
\author[**]{Kate K. Mays}
\author[**]{Lei Guo}
\author[*]{Margrit Betke}
\affil[*]{Computer Science Department, Boston University}
\email{\url{{betke,test}@bu.edu}}
\affil[**]{Emerging Media Studies, Boston University}
\email{\url{{betke,test}@bu.edu}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```