# Revtex: Print email after affiliation list

Tags: revtex

Using revtex 4.1, I'm trying to print the email address of the corresponding author directly in the affiliation list (after the affiliations), with an asterisk as is standard.
Independent of the journal style, I can get it either as a footnote on the first page with the `nobibnotes` option, or in the bibliography with the `bibnotes` option, but not directly after the affiliation list as desired.

I want to use the `notitlepage` and `superscriptaddress` format.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\author{Annoyed Physisict}
\email{annoyedphysicist@example.com}
\affiliation{Some University}

\author{Annoyed Chemist}
\affiliation{Some other University}


\title{Example for the revtex problem}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\blindtext

\bibliography{}
\end{document}
```

I have found multiple similar questions using the standard `article` class, for example [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428590/adding-email-under-author-affiliation), but none using revtex. I have not found the desired option in the revtex documentation.

Is there any secret revtex option that does this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

This is one possibility: printing a number instead of *, **, ...

[image: e]

```
\documentclass[notitlepage,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\emailx[1]{%
\move@AF%
\def\@affil{{\normalfont\,#1\strut}{}}%
}%


\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \author{Less Annoyed Physisict}
    
    \affiliation{Some University}
    \emailx{less-annoyedphysicist@example.com}
    
    \author{Less Annoyed Chemist}
    \affiliation{Some other University}
    \emailx{less-annoyedchemist@example.com}
    
    \title{Example for the revtex problem}
    \date{\today}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for coming up with this approach. Maybe there is a way to tweak the numbering to print "*" without messing up the count?